# Graph API end point to get the new "per-app post privacy" controls

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

A facebook user can now specify post privacy on per-application basis. This is explained by facebook on their [blog](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/543/).

In my web application I let people specify privacy settings while posting to their news feed. If a user has specified rather restrictive privacy than the one with he is posting to, facebook will enforce the restrictive settings as specified by user.

This results in bad user experience. I want to know if there is a way, preferably a Graph API end point, that lets me know this setting for a user. If I could fetch this information from Facebook, I could show a proper alert message, 'that to use a rather less restrictive privacy settings, (s)he will have to change his/her application specific privacy settings'. Or I could show only more restrictive privacy settings to the user while posting something in my UI.

Any pointer to where Facebook has documented this new *feature* from developer point of view in details is also appreciated.

Comment: Right now facebook does not provide any Graph API end point to get these. However a hack around this is to let a user post something with most open permissions from your app and request same post from facebook again. If permission of returned post doest not match with the one that you just posted, user has your app specific privacy settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the privacy_setting table (available via FQL) provides what you're looking for.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/privacy_setting/

*An FQL table that returns the default privacy settings that a user has set for an app.
To read the privacy table you need the following permissions:
User access_token
The data returned is for the user and the application associated with the given access token.
Example
Select the default settings you have set for this app (try this query for a test application):
SELECT name, value, description, allow, deny, networks, friends
FROM privacy_setting
WHERE name = 'default_stream_privacy'*

Comment: Facebook recently exposed app specific privacy settings via FQL. See: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/586/ . And since one can use Graph API to execute FQL queries, we can get this information via Graph API also see http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/579/