# How to get the “Posts on your behalf” setting of an app by Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

There are two kinds of privacy.

**1. Default privacy setting**
[image]

---

**2. Per-app privacy.** Set when user doing authentication or modify it at privacy setting page
[image]
and
[image]

According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/privacy_setting/, we could get the default privacy by FQL.

In this post https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/543/ said that users could modify per-app privacy for every apps in “Posts on your behalf: Who can see posts this app makes for you on your Facebook timeline?”

And https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/586/ said that we could retrieve app specific privacy settings for users. 
“Via the privacy_setting table table, apps can retrieve the privacy settings that a user has set for the app.”

But it did say how to retrieve privacy settings for a app rather than default privacy setting.

Before last year, maybe following discusses work correctly. But now I think that they were outdated:

- [How to determine the 'posts on my behalf' setting for a facebook application via the API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10002941/how-to-determine-the-posts-on-my-behalf-setting-for-a-facebook-application-via)
- [Graph API end point to get the new "per-app post privacy" controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502375/graph-api-end-point-to-get-the-new-per-app-post-privacy-controls)
- [Is there a way to know if a user changes the Default "Activity Privacy" for your FB app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823828/is-there-a-way-to-know-if-a-user-changes-the-default-activity-privacy-for-your)

Currently, there are not only default privacy setting but also per-app privacy setting that user could control them.

If we use

```
SELECT name, value, description, allow, deny, networks, friends
FROM privacy_setting
WHERE name = 'default_stream_privacy'
```

to retrieve privacy, the result is the same with 1. Default privacy setting.

---

And my question is, **how to get the setting value of 2. Per-app privacy?**

In FQL query above, is there any keyword could be put in name column rather than 'default_stream_privacy'?

It will influence the privacy of all new status/album/photo/video posts that were posted by app with API key. And I need to show privacy selections those are stricter than app privacy setting in customized UI.

Thanks for replying in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `default_stream_privacy` setting your app retrieves **is** the App-specific privacy setting - you can verify this in a few seconds by using Graph API Explorer tool, checking that value in the FQL table, modifying your privacy settings for that app in your privacy settings and checking again.

Answer (score 0):

OK... I found the root cause.

In this page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/privacy_setting/ ,
there is a link in (*try this query for a test application*).
The access token of this link is valid but is not correct. If we test *privacy_setting* table, the value of *default_stream_privacy* is not correct.

If we get a valid and correct access token from Graph API Explorer or app authentication, the return value will correct.

Thanks @igy !